# Squash the history with evil merges using git rebase

Tags: git

I want to squash first N commits using a git rebase:

```sh
/usr/share/git/rerere-train.sh --all
git rebase -i --rebase-merges --root
```

```
label onto

# Branch some-branch
reset [new root]
 
p ccc6a0a833 name
s 5a7651a1d2 name
s 255e0fd61a name
s 318a289219 name
s 988f43e817 name
s b11124c7ee name
s 9f026f4c6d name
p ccc6a0a833 name # first non-squashed commit
# ... and so on, nothing is modified below
```

When I do not change anything in an editor, then everything is ok. However, if I squash only a 2nd commit, then rebase is stopped, and I have to resolve conflicts manually, which is weird, because that one squashed commit is totally unrelated to the merge commits history

Comment: I think that interactive rebases are only applied when everything has been resolved otherwise they are aborted.

Answer (score 1):

When using `--rebase-merges`, Git doesn't *copy* the merge, because it can't.  Git *re-performs* the merge.

If you made an evil merge last time, and the evilness was not part of a conflict *or* you did not record this resolution with the rerere feature, the new merge will be a "good" merge.  This is likely to be the source of your problems here: the training step will only pick up any evilness from a conflict resolution.

To get the effect you want, you probably want to avoid `git rebase` entirely.  If you need it, and need to reproduce an evil merge, have Git stop after re-performing the merge, so that you can reintroduce the evilness.